# Updating a sketch to work with IDE 1.6.6

Tags: atmega328

I've got a MAX7456 chip and I am using [this (this is the unmodified one)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3cp4am1f271odcm/max7456.tar?dl=1) library with it. 
There's a sketch inside the examples folder (Max7456WriteTable) that I need to get to work to update the character table.

I modified three lines and then I got really stuck as I do not know how to continue. [This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sljvyngc27zver4/max7456_new.tar?dl=1) is the modified one.

```
In file included from Max7456Write.ino:2:0:
/tmp/build4608284042510222737.tmp/sketch/Max7456WriteTable.h:29:69153: warning: narrowing conversion of '243' from 'int' to 'const char' inside { } is ill-formed in C++11 [-Wnarrowing]
```

This happens for every item in the array. But that is not the only problem. (I'll skip a few hundred lines)

```
/tmp/build8855411239666100148.tmp/sketch/Max7456Write.cpp.o: In function `setup':
/home/t/Max7456Write.ino:13: undefined reference to `Max7456::Max7456(unsigned char)'
/home/t/Max7456Write.ino:19: undefined reference to `Max7456::activateOSD(bool)'
/home/t/Max7456Write.ino:44: undefined reference to `Max7456::getCARACFromProgMem(char const*, unsigned char, unsigned char*)'
/home/t/Max7456Write.ino:46: undefined reference to `Max7456::sendCharacter(unsigned char const*, unsigned char, unsigned char)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error compiling.
```

It takes a huge amount of time for it to abort the compilation.

Comment: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/1.6-Frequently-Asked-Questions#q-the-compiler-complains-about-prog_char-or-anything-that-begins-with-prog_-the-exact-error-is-iso-c-forbids-declaration-of-type-name-with-no-type-what-can-i-do

Comment: @Gerben I tried everything I could, it does not compile. I tried changing what is mentioned in the wiki page, it still does not work. The array no matter what I try either complains "duplicate const" or "not constant" or "invalid conversion from int to const char". As a newbie this is way too complex for me.

Comment: Yeah, it now works when I nuked my install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I change `prog_uchar` to `unsigned char` in both max7456.h and max7456.cpp the hello world example sketch compiles.

In Max7456WriteTable change

```
Max7456::getCARACFromProgMem(i,currentChar); //Because the table is too big for ram memory

osd->sendCharacter(currentChar,i); //We send currentChar at address i.
```

to

```
Max7456::getCARACFromProgMem(tableOfAllCharacters, i,currentChar); //Because the table is too big for ram memory

osd->sendCharacter(currentChar,i, 0); //We send currentChar at address i.
```

`0` is probably the wrong value, but at least it compiles.

Comment: Did that already. Check my second download link for my current progress.

Comment: Just move the contents of Max7456WriteTable.h to Max7456WriteTable.ino, and adding `#include <SPI.h>` makes the second download compile.

Comment: Are you using IDE 1.6.6?

Comment: 1.6.3. I updated to 1.6.6 and still compiles. https://www.dropbox.com/s/d3d0mkasvqrea8k/max7456.zip?dl=0

Comment: I updated my Arduino IDE version, wiped all libraries, redownloaded them, nuked all configurations and dynamic links I've created to keep consistency in my projects. It now finally works.